# Implementing Keras Model into website with Keras.js

Tags: javascript, keras

I have been trying to implement a basic Keras model generated in Python into a website using the [Keras.js](https://github.com/transcranial/keras-js) library. Now, I have the model trained and exported into the `model.json`, `model_weights.buf`, and `model_metadata.json` files. Now, I essentially copied and pasted test code from the github page to see if the model would load in browser, but unfortunately I am getting errors. Here is the test code. (EDIT: I fixed some errors, see below for remaining ones.)

```
var model = new KerasJS.Model({
    filepaths: {
        model: 'dist/model.json',
        weights: 'dist/model_weights.buf',
        metadata: 'dist/model_metadata.json'
  },
  gpu: true
});

    model.ready()
  .then(function() {
    console.log("1");
    // input data object keyed by names of the input layers
    // or `input` for Sequential models
    // values are the flattened Float32Array data
    // (input tensor shapes are specified in the model config)
    var inputData = {
      'input_1': new Float32Array(data)
    };
    console.log("2 " + inputData);
    // make predictions
    return model.predict(inputData);
  })
  .then(function(outputData) {
    // outputData is an object keyed by names of the output layers
    // or `output` for Sequential models
    // e.g.,
    // outputData['fc1000']
    console.log("3 " + outputData);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    // handle error
  });
```

EDIT: So I changed my program around a little to be compatible with JS 5 (that was a stupid mistake on my part), and now I have encountered a different error. This error is caught and then is logged. The error I get is: `Error: predict() must take an object where the keys are the named inputs of the model: input.` I believe this problem arises because my `data` variable is not in the correct format. I thought that if my model took in a 28x28 array of numbers, then `data` should also be a 28x28 array so that it could correctly "predict" the right output. However, I believe I am missing something and that is why the error is being thrown. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42744588/keras-model-predict-fails) question is very similar to mine, however it is in python and not JS. Again, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured out why this was happening. There were two problems. First, the `data` array needs to be flattened, so i wrote a quick function to take the 2D input and "flatten" it to be a 1D array of length 784. Then, because I used a Sequential model, the key name of the data should not have been `'input_1'`, but rather just `'input'`. This got rid of all the errors.

Now, to get the output information, we simply can store it in an array like this: `var out = outputData['output']`. Because I used the MNIST data set, `out` was a 1D array of length 10 that contained probabilities of each digit being the user-written digit. From there, you can simply find the number with the highest probability and use that as a prediciton for the model.